# Passing properties to react component.Getting Error - Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Be patient please, react newbie here

I'm trying to do a seemingly simple component which takes in a first and last names, allows a user to change the value and displays the updated value on button click.Just can't seem to get past these TS compile errors:

**1.add-user.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

type addUserProps = {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
}

class AddUser extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: addUserProps) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            firstName: props.firstName,
            lastName: props.lastName,
        };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        //'firstName' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'
        //alert(this.state.firstName);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TextField id="firstName" label="First Name" variant="outlined" value={this.state.firstName} />
                <TextField id="lastName" label="Last Name" variant="outlined" value={this.state.lastName}  />
                <Button variant="contained" onClick={this.handleClick}>Add Candidate</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddUser
```

Getting the following errors:

> Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'

> Property 'lastName' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'

**2.Trying to call the component like this:**

```
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import AddUser from "./lib/add-user"

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <AddUser firstName="John" lastName="Doe" />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root2")
  
);
```

Getting the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   TS2322  (TS) Type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
> Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation for [typing class component props](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/class_components)

You should do

```
class Component extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState>
```